# What kind of device would house 2 HDDs and provide non-RAID mirroring and NTFS support?

Tags: external-hard-drive

I've searched and searched, without success.

I want a device that:

- Can house two individual 3.5" hard drives.
- Can have the drives formatted NTFS.
- Will automatically mirror drive 1 onto drive 2 ***without*** RAID, just, whatever gets written to drive 1, also write it to drive 2.

So that I can take either drive out, install it into any Windows PC, and be able to use it.

A device that just does this off the shelf; *not* a DIY project.

Any such beast out there?